# Particular MySQL table structure

Tags: mysql, database-design

Could someone advise me on proper SQL architecture for this problem:

I am creating an app that has a dynamic number of options (option 1, option 2, option 3, etc...). I want the user to be able to select one of those options which will then increment a number associated with that option. How can I achieve a dynamic table, as I obviously can't pre-define 4 tables, for example, and have each be an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either I don't understand the question or you're overthinking it. Wouldn't just one table be enough, with two columns: one for the option name and one for the number associated with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a table like

```
CREATE TABLE `options` (
    option_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    occurrences INT UNSIGNED
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You can then run a query like:

```
UPDATE options SET occurrences = occurrences + 1 WHERE option_id = ____;
```

(Filling in the option_id based on what the visitor selected.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track which user selects which options, you could add a user-option table, and drop the occurrences counter from VoteyDeciple.

```
CREATE TABLE `UserOptions` (
    `uo_user` INT NOT NULL REFERENCES `users`(`user_id`),
    `uo_option` INT NOT NULL  REFERENCES `options`(`option_id`)
);
```

Then if you want to count occurrences of an option, you could use

```
SELECT count(*) as `occurrences` from UserOptions where uo_option={$option_id};
```